# a pointer to a bound function may only be used to call the function using a setter

Tags: c++, pointers, sdl, setter

I am using an SDL Template and I am trying to implement gravity into my code so I am trying to set a Y as the strength of my gravity in update but when I try to use a pointer to setY I always get an error "a pointer to a bound function may only be used to call the function using a setter" the code below is from my GameScene.cpp

```
#include "GameScene.h"

    GameScene::GameScene()
    {
        // Register and add game objects on constructor
        player = new Player();
        this->addGameObject(player);

        floor = new Floor();
        this->addGameObject(floor);
    }

    GameScene::~GameScene()
    {
        delete player;
    }

    void GameScene::start()
    {
        Scene::start();


        // Initialize any scene logic here
    }

    void GameScene::draw()
    {
        Scene::draw();
    }

    void GameScene::update()
    {
        Scene::update();

        if (player->getOnFloor() == false) {
            player->setY -= 1;
        }

        else {
            player->setY = 0;
        }
    }
```

This code is from my Player.h where the setters and getters are located

```
    #pragma once
    #include "GameObject.h"
    #include "common.h"
    #include "draw.h"

    class Player :
        public GameObject
    {
    public:
        void start();
        void update();
        void draw();

        //X Setter
        void setX(int x) {
            x = x;
        }
        //X Getter
        int getX() {
            return x;
        }
        //Y Setter
        void setY(int y) {
            y = y;
        }
        //Y Getter
        int getY() {
            return y;
        }
        //Height Setter
        void setHeight(int height) {
            height = height;
        }
        //Height Getter
        int getHeight() {
            return height;
        }
        //Width Setter
        void setWidth(int width) {
            width = width;
        }
        //Width Getter
        int getWidth() {
            return width;
        }
        //OnFloor Setter
        void setOnFloor(int onFloor) {
            onFloor = onFloor;
        }
        //OnFloor Getter
        int getOnFloor() {
            return onFloor;
        }
    private:
        SDL_Texture* texture;
        int x;
        int y;
        int height;
        int width;
        int speed;
        bool onFloor;

    };
```

I have tried putting () beside the setY like this

```
    if (player->getOnFloor() == false) {
        player->setY() -= 1;
    }

    else {
        player->setY)( = 0;
    }
```

But it still did not work, I was expecting it to make my player fall down but VS studio kept showing me the error

this may be a noobie question but I am still a noobie programmer so please bear with me

EDITED:

The player is now falling upwards, I tried doing -= 1 to make him fall downwards

```
void GameScene::update()
{
    Scene::update();

    if (player->getOnFloor() == false) {
        player->setY(player->getY() -= 1);
    }

    else {
        player->setY(0);
    }
}
```

but I get an error on player in "player->getY()" saying that expression must be a modifiable lvalue

Comment: `x = x` doesn't have any effect, maybe you meant `this->x = x` or just rename your parameter so it doesn't shadow the member. For your problem you seem to know how to call functions elsewhere in your code, just do the same here: `player->setY(0)`

Comment: ahhh okay thanks for the tip, I think I might change the x variable to something like side and the y to fall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is because you are trying to use the `setY` setter function as a variable. In order to use the setter function to set the `y` property of the `player` object, you need to call the `setY` function and pass in the new value for `y` as an argument. Here is how you would use the `setY` setter function in your `GameScene::update` function:

```
void GameScene::update()
{
    Scene::update();

    if (player->getOnFloor() == false) {
        player->setY(player->getY() + 1);
    }

    else {
        player->setY(0);
    }
}
```

Note that in this example, we are calling the `getY` getter function to get the current value of `y`, and then subtracting 1 from it before passing the result to the `setY` setter function. This will update the `y` property of the player object and make it fall down by 1 unit each time the update function is called.

Comment: ohhh yea that fixed it, man I feel so dumb thanks

Comment: well now my player is "falling" but he is falling upwards for some reason

Comment: Updated the code. I forgot that the Cartesian Plain originates from the top left on most game engines.